# Returning a value of type Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.XLANGMessage

Tags: c#, .net, xml, biztalk

Having a problem trying to create a function, as part of a BizTalk helper class that returns a value of type (Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.XLANGMessage). The function code is as follows:

```
public XLANGMessage UpdateXML (XLANGMessage inputFile)
{
   XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
   XLANGMessage outputFile;
   xDoc = (System.Xml.XmlDocument) inputFile[0].RetrieveAs(typeof(System.Xml.XmlDocument));

   // Modify xDoc document code here

   outputFile[0].LoadFrom(xDoc.ToString());
   return outputFile;
}
```

This code does not build as I receive an error stating "Use of unassigned local variable
'outputFile'. I have tried to initialize the 'outputFile' using the new keyword ( = new ....), but that also results in a build error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you have provided, change the line:

```
XLANGMessage outputFile;
```

to:

```
XLANGMessage outputFile = null;
```

and change the `TypeOf` to `typeof`

You might want to take a look at these two blog articles [here](http://vijaymodi.wordpress.com/2008/07/19/biztalk-pass-an-xlang-message-or-an-xlang-message-part-to-a-net-method-call-as-a-parameter-in-orchestration-call-net-assembly-to-update-the-xlangmessage-from-orchestration/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/darrenj/archive/2004/09/29/235719.aspx) that both mention some better ways of doing this including passing classes based on your xsd instead of the XLANGMessage, and using a stream instead of the `XMLDocument`.

---

After doing a quick once over with this (because I had a bad feeling) I'm not sure if BizTalk will consume the returned `XLANGMessage` the way you are trying. It fails with an unconstructed error when I try to use it in my test harness. Later tonight when I have some free time I'll see if there is an easy way to use the `XLANGMessage` directly in orchestration shapes. Add a comment if you manage to get it working before I update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return XLangMessage in this case. You can return the XmlDocument object itself and assign it a new variable in a Construct Message Shape.

Also it's not a good idea to return XLangMessage from user code.
See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995576.aspx